How do I center a UIImageView vertically in a UICollectionViewListCell as a custom accessory?
Please run the following UIKit app.
It uses a collection view with compositional layout (list layout) and a diffable data source.
It has one section with one row.
The cell has an image view as a leading accessory.

Unfortunately, as soon as I set an image for the image view, the accessory is no longer centered:

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, String>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        configureHierarchy()
        configureDataSource()
    }

    func configureHierarchy() {
        collectionView = .init(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: createLayout())
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.frame = view.bounds
    }
    
    func createLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
        UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout { section, layoutEnvironment in
            let config = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .insetGrouped)
            return NSCollectionLayoutSection.list(using: config, layoutEnvironment: layoutEnvironment)
        }
    }
    
    func configureDataSource() {
        let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String> { cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            let iv = UIImageView()
            iv.backgroundColor = .systemRed
//            iv.image = .init(systemName: "camera")
            iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            iv.frame.size = .init(
                width: 40,
                height: 40
            )
            
            cell.accessories = [.customView(configuration: .init(
                customView: iv,
                placement: .leading(),
                reservedLayoutWidth: .actual,
                maintainsFixedSize: true
            ))]
        }
        
        dataSource = .init(collectionView: collectionView) { collectionView, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
            collectionView.dequeueConfiguredReusableCell(using: cellRegistration, for: indexPath, item: itemIdentifier)
        }
        
        var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, String>()
        snapshot.appendSections(["main"])
        snapshot.appendItems(["demo"])
        dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false)
    }
}

This seems like a bug but then if I set the image view's size to 100x100, even without giving it an image, the cell doesn't resize, which makes me think I'm making a mistake.

It seems it has something to do with UIImageView's contentMode.
Putting UIImageView inside UIView fixes your problem
let containerView = UIView()
containerView.frame.size = .init(width: 40, height: 40)
let iv = UIImageView()
containerView.addSubview(iv)
iv.frame = containerView.bounds
iv.backgroundColor = .systemRed
iv.image = .init(systemName: "camera")
iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
cell.accessories = [
    .customView(configuration: .init(
        customView: containerView,
        placement: .leading(),
        reservedLayoutWidth: .actual,
        maintainsFixedSize: true
    ))
]

Result:


As for

if I set the image view's size to 100x100, even without giving it an
image, the cell doesn't resize

it doesn't have to since it doesn't know how to do it - you either have to provide constraints with auto-layout or manually set/calculate the sizing logic

I see, thank you. Well, if the cell doesn't self-size, I guess I would better use custom list content configurations in my case (which seem to have fewer auto layout-related bugs than cell subclasses, from my experience, as I show here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78405092/uicollectionviewlistcell-not-resizing)

This is happening because you trying to set wrong sizes and scaling.
Consider not set any heigh or width for that image and let system decide by itself
    let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String> { cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        iv.image = .init(systemName: "camera")
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        
        cell.accessories = [
            .customView(
                configuration: .init(
                    customView: iv,
                    placement: .leading()
                )
            )
        ]
    }


or
    let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String> { cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        iv.image = .init(systemName: "camera")
        iv.contentMode = .center
        iv.frame.size = .init(width: 40, height: 40)
        cell.accessories = [
            .customView(
                configuration: .init(
                    customView: iv,
                    placement: .leading(),
                    reservedLayoutWidth: .actual,
                    maintainsFixedSize: true
                )
            )
        ]
    }



However if you need bigger image you can try something like so:
red square on the same place, but set origin fixes your alignment issue
    let cellRegistration = UICollectionView.CellRegistration<UICollectionViewListCell, String> { cell, indexPath, itemIdentifier in
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        iv.image = .init(systemName: "camera")
        iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        iv.bounds.origin = .init(x: 0, y: -(cell.bounds.height/2))
        iv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        iv.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        
        cell.accessories = [
            .customView(
                configuration: .init(
                    customView: iv,
                    placement: .leading()
                )
            )
        ]
    }



Thank you, the camera looks centered in you last screenshot, but if you use the system image named "phone.fill", instead, for instance, it doesn't. Maybe the solution should involve centering the image view itself vertically to the cell

@Filippo try to play with origin position from bounds, it's relies on object itself, not container
